# Bayesian Statistics Example clarification

Tags: probability, bayesian

lets assume we have the following data:

$$
\text{Test Result} | \text{Has Disease}\\
1 | 1\\
1 | 1\\
1 | 0\\
0 | 0\\
0 | 0\\
0 | 0\\
0 | 1\\
1 | 1\\
1 | 0\\
1 | 1
$$

Lets denote P(B) as the probability that one has the disease and P(A) as the probability of a positive test result.

Is it correct to calculate

$$P(B) = \frac{6}{10}$$

and

$$P(A) = \frac{5}{10}$$?

Furthermore, let's evaluate P(B=1|A=1) as the probability of having the disease given that the test result is positive.

Is it correct to say that $$P(B=1|A=1) = \frac{4}{10}$$?

Thanks for any corrections / answers.

Comment: I think you might have mixed up the definitions of $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Comment: No it is not correct. What you have written is $P(B=1\cap A=1)$, whereas it should've been $P(B=1\cap A=1)/P(A=1)$ which is $2/3$. When you are calculating conditional probability, your sample space modifies, so your new sample space are only those entries in data which have $A=1$, which are $6$ in number.  Now out of those $6$, you have $4$ in which $B=1$ as well, so $P(B=1|A=1)=4/6=2/3$

Comment: @DevanshKamra Thank you!